# Asignar un document.getElementById en Js FUERA DE UNA FUNCIÓN

Tags: javascript, html

mi duda es como asignarle a una variable un getElementById por fuera de una función. Porque solamente puedo si esa variable la creo dentro de una función, pero no para el afuera. Quiero poder hacerlo al principio sin tener una función asignada, gracias.

les dejo el código Html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Ejercicio 2</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Número 1:</p><input id="num1" type="number"><br>
    <p>Número 2:</p><input id="num2" type="number"><br><br>
    <button onclick="totalNumeros()">Mostrar todos los números:</button><p id="numeros">prueba</p>
    <button>Mostrar totalidad de números:</button><p id="totalidad"></p>
    <button>Mostrar suma: </button><p id="suma"></p>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

y les dejo el código JS:

```
var num1 = document.getElementById('num1').value;
var num2 = document.getElementById("num2").value;


function totalNumeros(){
    document.getElementById("numeros").innerHTML = num1;
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido Juan, podrías actualizar la pregunta con el mínimo código necesario para entender lo que estás haciendo y hacer pruebas para ayudar lo más rápido posible?

Comment: Listo! Ya lo actualicé

Comment: No se entiende esta pregunta. En su código tiene 2 variables fuera de una función  a las cuales le esta asignando un document.getElementById, entonces que es exactamente lo que quiere hacer?

Comment: sí, pero en el código no me funciona, cuando ejecuto la página, no le asigna el valor del imput a la variable. Lo intenté con queryselector y tampoco anda

Comment: para tomar el valor del input debes colocarle un addEventListener(change) al input asi dispara una funcion que haga lo que necesitas. Prueba a poner esta linea <input id="num1" type="number" value="123"> y veras como si toma el valor

Answer (score 1):

Tienes mal concebida la lógica de programación. Veo 2 problemas aquí

1. `num1` y `num2` siempre serán `undefined`, dado que al iniciar el script y recuperar sus valores, eso es lo que trae por defecto. No es una comunicación de dos vías, es decir, si tu premisa es que el escribir un número se actualice la variable, es un error de conceptualización.
2. Tu etiqueta `<p>` no tiene una propiedad de `innerHTML`, si no de `textContent`

Yo lo haría de la siguiente forma

```js
function totalNumeros() {
 const num1 = document.getElementById('num1').value || 0;
 const num2 = document.getElementById('num2').value || 0;
 
 document.getElementById('numeros').textContent = num1;
 
}
```

```html
<p>Número 1:</p><input id="num1" type="number"><br>
    <p>Número 2:</p><input id="num2" type="number"><br><br>
    <button onclick="totalNumeros()">Mostrar todos los números:</button><p id="numeros">prueba</p>
    <button>Mostrar totalidad de números:</button><p id="totalidad"></p>
    <button>Mostrar suma: </button><p id="suma"></p>
```

Intenta utilizar siempre `const` en lugar de `var` (Si la variable puede mutar en tipo de dato o ser reemplazada por otro valor más adelante, usa `let`)

Básicamente lo que hice es recoger el `num1` cada vez que se da click al botón, no sólo al iniciar el script. Si necesitas forzosamente la variable fuera de la función, aunque para mi no tiene sentido, podrías hacer esto

```
let numExterior = 0;
function totalNumeros() {
 const num1 = document.getElementById('num1').value || 0;
 const num2 = document.getElementById('num2').value || 0;
 numExterior = num1;
 
 document.getElementById('numeros').textContent = numExterior;
 
}
```

De esta forma siempre tendrás una referencia de la variable, dentro y fuera de un scope

Comment: Gracias! Después de un mes leyendo teoría de JS entiendo muchísimo más estas cosas. Es incompatible con JS pretender que una variable se actualice sola.